How do I run a SEDE query for this site?
The Stack Exchange Data Explorer lets you write SQL queries to find questions, answers, comments, users etc across the StackExchange network, but the query interface throws an error if I try to select Psychology & Neuroscience.
The problem seems to be the ampersand in the site's name; all the other sites with ampersands (Unix & Linux, Science Fiction & Fantasy, English Language & Usage, etc) have it replaced with "and" in the site dropdown.
In principle it seems possible to bypass this error if you can guess the site's internal name in SEDE, but the obvious psychology brings me a "page not found". (For example, I can run visit https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/1677462/common-typos-lite-newest and then replace unix in the URL with ell to get the same query for the English Language Learners site.)
What can I do to escalate this? (Should I be asking on the main meta?)

As a workaround, one can change URL to cogsci like here: https://data.stackexchange.com/cogsci/query/1677462/common-typos-lite-newest

@Martin Thanks! I would never have guessed that abbreviation.

I found cogsi by checking the link given in the list of sites on the SEDE homepage.

Brilliant; I looked in the schema documentation and elsewhere but missed the, in retrospect, obvious.

This was mentioned here - the correct URL is cogsci.

My immediate problem is solved, but the bug in the dropdown should still be reported to the maintainers. Should I try to get this migrated to the main meta site, or just wait? Or ask again there with just the dropdown bug?

Probably best to make a new post focused narrowly on the bug; I'd also include the context you've learned here, i.e. that cogsci is the name in data explorer (note that the site has had a name change and used to be called Cognitive Science; same is true for other sites like Health now Medical Sciences). It can be either here or main meta, but I'd at least search main meta to see if someone else has raised the issue there.

Thanks for the very quick and helpful responses I got. Turns out that the site abbreviation cogsci can be used as a workaround for the time being.
I have separately reported the broken dropdown on the main meta; Data Explorer throws server error when attempting to query Psychology & Neuroscience
